# Wrong initial user location in MapView gps

Tags: swift, gps, mkmapview, cllocationmanager, mkuserlocation

I want to get the user location, that's what I did:
I set locationManager in my ViewController:

```
var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

func setUpLocationManager() {
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.distanceFilter = 5
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
    mapView?.showsUserLocation = true
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}
```

Here is the function that is called once the location is updated:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    if !locations.isEmpty {
            print("\(locations[0])")
        }
    }
}
```

It prints the initial location of the user position (see image), but I consider it wrong, because it an approximation.
I also tried with:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didUpdate userLocation: MKUserLocation) {
    let accuracy = userLocation.location?.horizontalAccuracy
    if accuracy == locationManager.desiredAccuracy {
        print("\(locations[0])")
    }
}
```

But it never prints the location because `locationManager.desiredAccuracy` is equal to -2 and `accuracy` is always > 0.

This what I see on the mapView:

[image]
[image]

Initially the user pin shows a position near to the real position (but it is not right), subsequently the user pin moves to the real user position. 
I want the function `didUpdateLocations` to be called when the user pin is on the right position.
My question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941981/mkmapviews-user-location-is-wrong-on-startup-or-resume), but it was in objective-c.

Any hints? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ref. [MKMapView's user location is wrong on startup or resume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941981/mkmapviews-user-location-is-wrong-on-startup-or-resume)

Swift version:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didUpdate userLocation: MKUserLocation) {
    let accuracy = userLocation.location?.horizontalAccuracy
    if accuracy ... {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand what to enter inside the if condition, because if I compare it with locationManager.desiredAccuracy it always returns false because desiredAccuracy is equal to -2.